# Is there a way to check if value in object is set without using foreach?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the following JSON object:

```
{
  "screen": 1,
  "parameters": {
    "title": "Fill in the form:",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "type": 2,
        "name": "A",
        "label": "Lorem ipsum",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "type": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "label": "Lorem ipsum",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the code I access the values using `$screen = /*object*/; $screen->parameters->values`.

Is there a fast way to check if the values of answer A and B are filled in? I tought something like this:

```
if(isset(A) && isset(B)) { ... }
```

For those who are interested, I use laravel 5, maybe there is a method for it?

*It looks like I need an foreach, but I rather avoid those in this case...*

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not with the current structure. You could however change the structure a bit to support this. You could use an object instead of an array and use the name as keys:

```
{
  "screen": 1,
  "parameters": {
    "title": "Fill in the form:",
    "values": {
      "A":{
        "id": 13,
        "type": 2,
        "label": "Lorem ipsum",
        "value": 10
      },
      "B":{
        "id": 14,
        "type": 2,
        "label": "Lorem ipsum",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You could then use your isset method.

```
isset( $screen->parameters->values->A );
```

You can still loop over the values as you can turn this whole thing in an associative array by passing true to json_decode as a second parameter. I for one am not a big fan of my own answer, and would probably just loop the thing, but it may still answer your question.

**edit:** I forgot that if you add true to json_decode, you also access your properties like this:

```
isset( $screen['parameters']['values']['A'] );
```

Comment: Ah, this looks OK indeed, thanks:) I need to rebuild a part of the API do..